What is a "responsibility" in the single responsibility principle?
I'm taking a course on C# programming here: https://www.udemy.com/course/ultimate-csharp-masterclass/?couponCode=KEEPLEARNING
In it, there's a lecture on encapsulation. The instructor gives an example of how a Rectangle class can encapsulate both fields and methods:
class Rectangle
{
    int _width;
    int _height;
    
    public Rectangle(int width, int height)
    {
        _width = width;
        _height = height;
    }
    
    public int CalculateArea()
    {
        return _width * _height;
    }
    
    public int CalculateCircumference()
    {
        return _width * 2 + _height * 2;
    }
}

This is an example of encapsulation because both the fields (_width and _height) and methods (CalculateArea() and CalculateCircumference()) are encapsulated in one class. She drives the point home by showing an alternate implementation in which encapsulation is not leveraged:
class Rectangle
{
    public int Width;
    public int Height;
    
    public Rectangle(int width, int height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }
}

class RectangleCalculator
{
    public int CalculateArea(Rectangle rect)
    {
        return rect.Width * rect.Height;
    }
    
    public int CalculateCircumference(Rectangle rect)
    {
        return rect.Width * 2 + Rect.Height * 2;
    }
}

She says the first example is better because encapsulation is one of the strengths of OOP and should be used.
However, this got me thinking about the Single Responsibility principle and her example seems to conflict with it. Isn't storing the width and height of a rectangle a different responsibility than calculating its area or circumference? Therefore, wouldn't it be better to split those responsibilities off into different classes? I asked this of the instructor and she said no because the responsibility of the Rectangle class is to represent a rectangle and this could mean having methods to calculate things like area or circumference.
This got me thinking that I don't know what a "responsibility" is. Sure, you could say the responsibility of the Rectangle class is to represent a rectangle, but this could be split up into smaller responsibilities (store the width and height, calculate the area, calculate the circumferences, etc.). So how do we determine the proper way to describe a class's responsibility?
Robert C. Martin, the author of the single responsibility principle, expresses it as "a class should have only one reason to change." But let's say a change is requested to have the Rectangle class store the width and height as floating point values instead of ints:
class Rectangle
{
    public float Width;
    public float Height;
    
    public Rectangle(float width, float height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }
    
    // more code
}

...and then another change is requested to give the Rectangle a color:
class Rectangle
{
    public float Width;
    public float Height;
    public Color Color;
    
    public Rectangle(float width, float height, Color color)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        Color = color
    }
    
    // more code
}

These are two different reasons to change, are they not? And yet, why should the color not count as one of the rectangle's properties just as much as its width and height?
So for me, the question of what a "responsibility" is only gets deferred to the question of what a "reason to change" is. Can anyone shed any light on this? Thanks!

This is likely to get closed as a question asking for an opinion. That being said, colo(u)r is not an inherent property of a rectangle and could be relevant to any shape but calculating the area of a shape is specific to the type of shape and will be different for other shapes.

So I guess you're saying color could be moved to a parent class (a Shape class) and CalculateArea() and CalculateCircunference() could be implemented by an interface (though, as implementations, the responsibility of doing the calculations would still be the Rectangle class). But what does that say about how to define a class's "responsibility"? Is it just based on the purpose of creating the class in the first place? I name it after what it's supposed to do? And that's its responsibility?

"Is it just based on the purpose of creating the class in the first place?" Not necessarily,  as further development may include refactoring which moves responsibilities about. It may be that at some point down the line, it makes sense to have a single class which calculates the circumference and areas of all shapes. In short, it depends.

I think this question is more likely to get closed because it should ideally be split into 2 questions. You should close this one and add 2 separate ones (1) about encapsulation (2) about SRP violation (which I don't think is there).

There is no better explanation of the SRP than the author's blog. That being said, no one really knows what it means and you can easily find other blogs and discussions across the Internet with a dozen conflicting viewpoints. Your instructor's definition will be whichever one supports the examples in her course.

Ah, pure honesty, jaco! It's like a breath of fresh air. :D

Unfortunately, the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) is quite ambiguous. Firstly, there are several formulations of this principle. Secondly, these formulations do not give a clear answer: how to calculate the number of class responsibilities by looking at it. Given the above, I would not apply this principle in the context of your problem.
But there is a very formal pattern that gives a specific answer in the context of your problem. This is the information expert pattern (General Responsibility Assignment Software Patterns).

Problem: What is a basic principle by which to assign responsibilities
to objects?
Solution: Assign responsibility to the class that has the
information needed to fulfill it.

In your case, the Rectangle has the necessary information to calculate the area and circumference, so applying the information expert pattern we must place the appropriate methods into it.
